# Are there any ways to get UEFI boot items on Windows

Tags: windows, uefi

I've been working on UEFI and GPT recently. I want to get the UEFI boot item under WIndows, but I looked at MSDN and found no suitable API. Please ask me how to query the UEFI boot item under Windows

It just likes this below:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfirmwareenvironmentvariablea) function to get the BootOrder variable first and then the single boot options (Boot####).

You need the [SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants) privilege to call GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA.

The structures and names of the required variables are defined in the [uefi specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_9_2021_03_18.pdf), starting at chapter 3.

```
DWORD BootOrderContentLength;
DWORD Error;
BYTE BootOrderContent[256];

BootOrderContentLength = GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA(
    "BootOrder",
    "{8BE4DF61-93CA-11D2-AA0D-00E098032B8C}",
    (VOID*)BootOrderContent,
    (DWORD)sizeof(BootOrderContent));

if (BootOrderContentLength == 0) {
    Error = GetLastError();
    //...
}
```